# How to get entity id(order id) in success phtml

Tags: magento2, orders, onepage-checkout, sales-order, order-success-page

In my `success.phtml` , $block->getViewOrderUrl() gives a order url with order id(entity id) .

`dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Magento/Checkout/Test/Block/Onepage/Success.php`

> /sales/order/view/order_id/173569/

How to get this order id alone - `173569` in success.phtml.

I don't see any functions in success.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can try this one to get the `order Id` alone:</s>

<s>$block->getOrderId()</s>

UPDATE:

You can override the Block file of checkout success one page using `preference` and define your own method to get the `order Id`.
Try this:
In your custom module's `di.xml` file add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage\Success" />
</config>
```

Now create `Success.php` Block file in Folder **`Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

/**
 * One page checkout success page
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Success extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    /**
     * Render additional order information lines and return result html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalInfoHtml()
    {
        return $this->_layout->renderElement('order.success.additional.info');
    }

    /**
     * Initialize data and prepare it for output
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->prepareBlockData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Prepares block data
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareBlockData()
    {
        $order = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();

        $this->addData(
            [
                'is_order_visible' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'view_order_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/view/',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'print_url' => $this->getUrl(
                    'sales/order/print',
                    ['order_id' => $order->getEntityId()]
                ),
                'can_print_order' => $this->isVisible($order),
                'can_view_order'  => $this->canViewOrder($order),
                'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId()
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Is order visible
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isVisible(Order $order)
    {
        return !in_array(
            $order->getStatus(),
            $this->_orderConfig->getInvisibleOnFrontStatuses()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Can view order
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function canViewOrder(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)
            && $this->isVisible($order);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function getContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }


    /**
    * @return string
    * getOrigId
    */
    public function getOrigId()
    {
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getEntityId();
    }

}
```

Then you can now get the `Order Id(Entity Id)` in your `.phtml` template like this:

```
$block->getOrigId()
```

Comment: $block->getOrderId() will get me entity id ? whats the difference between        $block->getViewOrderUrl()->getId() and $block->getOrderId()

Comment: Yeah, the `$block->getOrderId()` will get the entity id. Actually, I am not sure with the `$block->getViewOrderUrl()->getId()` but you can check.

Comment: `$block->getOrderId()` gave me increment id not entitty id,  `/sales/order/view/order_id/173569/` , this 173569 is entity id which output of `$block->getViewOrderUrl()` , i just wanted 173569

Comment: I think better if you would override the Block file for checkout success.phtml file and create your own method to get order Id

Comment: @summu updated my answer please check